# I am trying to display appointments by week or month but I am not able to (C#)

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, radio-button

The datagridview is showing the appointments by week even if I check the month radio button

```
Dictionary<int, Hashtable> parsedAppointments = new Dictionary<int, Hashtable>();
// Adjusts appointments that will end up in calendar based on if the Week or Month view is chosen.
foreach (var appointment in appointments)
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Parse(appointment.Value["start"].ToString());
    DateTime endTime = DateTime.Parse(appointment.Value["end"].ToString());
    DateTime today = DateTime.UtcNow;

    if (weekView)
    {
        DateTime sunday = today.AddDays(-(int)today.DayOfWeek);
        DateTime saturday = today.AddDays(-(int)today.DayOfWeek + (int)DayOfWeek.Saturday);

        if (startTime >= sunday && endTime < saturday)
        {
            // only include the apps that get here
            parsedAppointments.Add(appointment.Key, appointment.Value);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
        DateTime lastDayOfMonth = firstDayOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
        if (startTime >= firstDayOfMonth && endTime < lastDayOfMonth)
        {
            //  only include apps that get here
            parsedAppointments.Add(appointment.Key, appointment.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Try to see what the event handler does of the months radiobutton.

Comment: What is `weekView`? Is that the radio button? If so shouldn't you check `weekView.Checked`? Also how are your radio buttons arranged? If they're not grouped, `weekView` being false would not automatically mean `monthView` is true.

Comment: weekView is a parameter

Comment: @Katko, so if you place breakpoints and debug, what does it do? Do you get right `veekView` value, thus executing correct part of condition, but it's not working probperly? Or is it executing a wrong part of condition?